# Enum boolean in C#

Tags: c#, enums, boolean

I have this method

```
public enum Values
{
    True= true,
    False=false
};
public static string GetValues(bool values)
{
    string status = "";
    switch (values)
    {
        case(bool)UIHelper.Values.False:

    }
}
```

I want to have this `enum` as `boolean`. It says, that:

> Values cannot be casted as bool.

How can I do it so I can have it `boolean`?

Comment: 0 and 1 map to false and true

Comment: If you want a boolean, then why not stick with using `bool` instead of an enum?

Comment: @CallumBradbury Actually zero maps to false and not zero maps to true.

Comment: @rory.ap that's what I said bro

Comment: @CallumBradbury -- bro, no you said just 1 maps to true, bro.  Bro, I mean 1 and any other number other than zero.  Bro.

Comment: @CallumBradbury -- Here's your comment: "0 and **1** map to false and true"  Do you see the bold number "1"?  All I'm saying is that -2 also maps to true.  So does 153.  So does 123412341234.

Comment: @rory.ap bro bro bro bro bro. 0 maps to false, and 1 maps to true, this is what I said and it is correct. It's irrelevant for the question being asked, whether any non-zero maps to true.

Comment: The word he had to add was *respectively* to make it correct... From my POV it was clear @rory.ap

Comment: @rory.ap Actually in C# no integer values map to `bool`.  Also am I suppose to say Bro now?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I wasn't saying his was wrong.  I was modifying his statement to be more specific.

Comment: @juharr -- Yes, bro.  This is what I mean: `var x = 5; var y = Convert.ToBoolean(x); // <--- y == true`.

Comment: I don't think the you should want to convert from `bool` to your enum.  The argument to your method should be the enum type instead.

Comment: @rory.ap my statement did not need modifying to be more specific... bro

Comment: @juharr Well,I need this method, to convert a bool to string so I can display it in an excel sheet.

Comment: @JessWss In that case just use an `if` statement.  I don't see why you'd need an enum for that, or use constants like Patrick recommends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, you can map to 0 (`Service`) and 1 (`Serial`), but why map to that in the first place? Why not use bool from the start?

```
public static class UnlPointValues
{
    public const bool Serial = true;
    public const bool Service = false;
}

public static string GetUnloadingPointValues(bool values)
{
    string status = "";
    switch (values)
    {
        case UIHelper.UnlPointValues.Serial:

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to stick to `enum` you can implement an *extension method*:

```
  public enum Values {
    True,
    False,
    // and, probably, some other options
  };

  public static class ValuesExtensions {
    public static bool ToBoolean(this Values value) {
      // which options should be treated as "true" ones
      return value == Values.False;
    }
  }
```

...

```
// you, probably want to check if UIHelper.Values is the same as values 
if (values == UIHelper.Values.ToBoolean()) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you need an `enum` here.

```
public static string GetUnloadingPointValues(bool isSerial)
{
    return isSerial ? "Serial" : "Service";
}
```

Or whatever `string` values you want to map.

Answer (score 0):

Use `0` for `false` and `1` for `true` instead combined with `Convert.ToBoolean`

> true if value is not zero; otherwise, false.

```
public enum UnlPointValues
{
    Serial = 1,  //true
    Service = 0  //false
};

public static string GetUnloadingPointValues(bool values)
{
    string status = "";
    switch (values)
    {
        case (Convert.ToBoolean((int)UIHelper.UnlPointValues.Serial)):
        break;
        case (Convert.ToBoolean((int)UIHelper.UnlPointValues.Service)):
        break;
    }
}
```